# Why this code is crashing when call procedure in loop?

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, protected-mode, bochs

I tried to write own simple bootloader, I had this code:

```
.code16 # Generate 16 bit code

.globl set_protected_mode
.globl set_real_mode
__init:
call set_protected_mode
call set_real_mode
jmp __init

# jmp init # Jump to init function in init.c

set_real_mode:
cli
mov %cr0, %eax
and $0xfffffffe,%eax
mov %eax, %cr0
sti
jmp %cs:__set_another_mode_done

set_protected_mode:
cli # Disable interrupts
mov %cr0, %eax
or $0x1, %eax
mov %eax, %cr0
sti # Enable interrupts
jmp %cs:__set_another_mode_done

__set_another_mode_done:
ret # Back to calling function in protected or real mode
```

And It crashes after some time in protected mode.

I'm using GNU Assembler v2.24, Ubuntu 14.04 and testing in bochs.

Log from bochs:

```
00014944437e[CPU0 ] interrupt(): gate descriptor is not valid sys seg (vector=0x08)
========================================================================
Event type: ERROR
Device: [CPU0 ]
Message: interrupt(): gate descriptor is not valid sys seg (vector=0x01)
```

Can anyone explain why it crashed?

Is there anything can I do to fix it?

Comment: What do you think will happen when you hit the `ret`? Hint: nothing good. It will be a #GP which is vector #8 but you didn't even set up an IDT. Also interrupt #1 is the keyboard, presumably you pressed a key. The timer should also still be ticking which will cause another error. I am surprised you didn't hit a triple fault reset. PS: do you even have a GDT loaded?

Comment: Why are you trying to go into REAL mode after PROTECTED mode? Have you set up an IDT before entering PROTECTED mode? If not, interrupts will go anywhere and crash.